# assign class types to columns of data.frame from vector

Tags: r, rbind

I have 2 data frames (with identical structures) I'd like to combine using rbind but want to make sure none of the factor variables get screwed up.

Is there a way to :

1. Store the pre-combined structure of one of the data frames in a character vector
2. Convert both data frames to all character-type
3. `rbind` the 2 data frames
4. Reassign the variable types using the character vector.

It would look something like this:

```
iris1 <- iris
iris2 <- iris
type1 <- sapply(iris1, class)

iris1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris1, as.character))
iris2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris2, as.character))
iris3 <- rbind(iris1, iris2)

str(iris3) <- type1
```

This doesn't work but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a more sophisticated approach like `dplyr::bind_rows`? It would be more helpful to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) there a simple `rbind()` does not work as you intend.

Comment: `type1 <- paste0("as.", type1); iris3[] <- lapply(seq_along(type1), function(x) match.fun(type1[x])(iris3[[x]])); iris3`?

Comment: Why would you convert all the columns? That's going to result in serious loss of information particularly for numeric values. Is your main concern about using `rbind` when `factor` levels don't match in the two `data.frame`s being combined?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1: Yes - the concern is mainly around the factor level issue.

Comment: As @MrFlick suggested, then, it would be better if you could share a small example where `rbind` does not work as you expect...